# How do I Remove a Local Branch in VS22

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

How can I remove a local branch in VS22?
I don't want to delete this branch from the repository, I just want to remove the branch from my list of local branches.

Working in a lot of branches makes the list increase sizes, and I wanted to keep everything tidy

EDIT: I know it doesn't make sense, but in this project, branches aren't deleted. So, every time, I stop using one branch, I merge it, but it still stays in the local list of branches

Comment: This sounds mopre like a source control question than a Visual Studio question!

Comment: I think it depends, I guess the same result can be made throw code. But VS has is one git integration, and maybe there is an option to achieve this.

Comment: Why have you got that many branches, surely you're not actively working on them all? If you are, why are you not completing the task and merging them?

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, but in this project, branches aren't deleted. So, every time, I stop using one branch, I merge it, but it still stays in the local list of branches

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so you want to keep the local branch but hide it in VS Git explorer (or whatever it's called). I'm not aware of a way to do this natively and I would question why you have so many local branches - are you really actively working on them all.

If you really wanted to you could make a second clone of the repository and only pull the local branches from the first clone you want to see in to the second. This feels like a lot of effort as you are going to have keep pushing your changes back to the first clone to keep it up to date too.

### **Update:**

#### Comment from OP

> Your solution is close to what I'm using now, that is when the local list stays to big, I delete the project and clone a new one, to get a fresh local branches list.

I would suggest modifying what you already do then. You could delete the branches from your "local clone" once they had been pushed to your "local origin", you would only need to keep branches you are actively working on in your "local clone". No need to bin it off, re-clone each time.

If you keep on top of it and do it every time you no longer want to see a specific local branch it would probably be much easier to manage. I know the whole multiple origins thing might confuse things some times but it would keep your "local clone" much "cleaner" and you can always get back those branches if you need to.

Another idea might be to tag the heads of those local branches once you are done with them and delete the branch. The commits will still be accessible and you could recreate those branches if you ever needed to... That might even work with a single local repository. Not sure how VS surfaces tags in the Git

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, but in this project, branches aren't deleted. So, every time, I stop using one branch, I merge it, but it still stays in the local list of branches.

Your solution is close to what I'm using now, that is when the local list stays to big, I delete the project and clone a new one, to get a fresh local branches list. However, this is annoying...

Comment: I've had a few more thoughts. Check the update.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how I can "delete the branch from my local clone"?

Comment: `git branch -d <branch name>` although if it's not fully merged you may have to use a capital `-D` to force delete i.e. `git branch -D <branch name>`